# What is wrong with my OpenGL with SDL2 code?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-2

I am unable to draw to a window I have created with the code written below.

What I know is correct:

- sdl2 init
- glew init
- window creation
- context creation

What I think might be the problem:

- glsl shaders, BUT they ARE compiling successful.
- glVertexAttribPointer()
- missing function calls?

What I have ruled out with error checking:

- sdl init
- glew init
- window creation
- context creation
- vertex shader compilation
- fragment shader compilation
- program linking

note: I have written my shaders inline (glsl.h).

main.cpp

```
    #include <GL\glew.h>
    #include <SDL.h>
    #include <glm\glm.hpp>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "glsl.h"

    #define SDL_INIT_FAIL -1
    #define IMAGE_INIT_FAIL 0

    #define glsl(version, glsl) "#version " #version "\n" #glsl

    namespace glsl { namespace vs {
    //VERTEX SHADERS
    //=========================
    // simple VS
    //=========================
    constexpr GLchar * const simple = glsl(450 core, 
        layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;

        void main() {
            gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
        }
        );

    } namespace fs {
    //FRAGMENT SHADERS
    //=========================
    // simple FS
    //=========================
    constexpr GLchar * const simple = glsl(450 core,
        out vec4 color;

        void main() {
            color = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        }       
        );

} }

    constexpr GLint image_Flags{ IMG_INIT_PNG | IMG_INIT_JPG };
    constexpr GLuint init_Flags{ SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_EVENTS },window_Flags{ SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE};
    constexpr GLchar * window_Title{ "Sprite Game with OpenGL" };
    constexpr GLint window_Width{ 1200 }, window_Height{ 740 }, window_PositionX{ SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED },
        window_PositionY{ SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED };

    int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

        std::cout << glsl::vs::simple << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << glsl::fs::simple << std::endl << std::endl;
    system("pause");

    if (SDL_Init(init_Flags) == SDL_INIT_FAIL) {
        std::cerr << "error init sdl" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 23);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 5);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

    SDL_Window * window = nullptr;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(window_Title, window_PositionX, window_PositionY, window_Width, window_Height, window_Flags);
    if (window == nullptr) {
         std::cerr << "error window is nullptr" << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();
        return 4;
    }

    SDL_GLContext context = nullptr;
    context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    if (context == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "error context is nullptr" << std::endl;
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        window = nullptr;
        SDL_Quit();
        return 5;
    }

    glewExperimental = true;

    GLenum glewError = glewInit();
    if (glewError != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cerr << "error glew init: " << glewGetErrorString(glewError) << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();
        return 3;
    }
    std::cout << "OpenGL Version " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

    struct Mouse
    {
        Uint32 mouseState = 0;
        GLint mx{ 0 }, my{ 0 };
    };
    struct Input {
        Mouse mouse;
        SDL_Event e;
        const Uint8 * keyState = nullptr;

    } input;
    struct Shader {
        GLuint program;
        GLuint vertexShader;
        GLuint fragmentShader;
    } shader;

    shader.vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(shader.vertexShader, 1, &glsl::vs::simple, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader.vertexShader);

    GLint vertexCompilei;
    GLchar vsiInfo[512];
    glGetShaderiv(shader.vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &vertexCompilei);
    if (vertexCompilei == GL_FALSE) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader.vertexShader, sizeof vsiInfo, NULL, vsiInfo);
        std::cerr << vsiInfo << std::endl;
    }

    shader.fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(shader.fragmentShader, 1, &glsl::fs::simple, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader.fragmentShader);

    GLint fragmentCompilei;
    GLchar fsiInfo[512];
    glGetShaderiv(shader.fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &fragmentCompilei);
    if (fragmentCompilei == GL_FALSE) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader.fragmentShader, sizeof fsiInfo, NULL, fsiInfo);
        std::cerr << fsiInfo << std::endl;
    }

    shader.program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shader.program, shader.vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shader.program, shader.fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shader.program);

    GLint programLinki;
    GLchar programInfo[512];
    glGetProgramiv(shader.program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &programLinki);
    if (programLinki == GL_FALSE) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shader.program, sizeof programInfo, NULL, programInfo);
        std::cerr << programInfo << std::endl;
    }


    struct Object {
        GLuint VAO;
        GLuint VBO;
    } object;

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &object.VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &object.VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(object.VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, object.VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof vertices, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof GLfloat * 3, (GLvoid*)0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    do {
        glViewport(0, 0, window_Width, window_Height);
        glClearColor(0.3f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shader.program);
        glBindVertexArray(object.VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glUseProgram(0);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);

        SDL_PollEvent(&input.e);
        input.keyState = SDL_GetKeyboardState(0);
        input.mouse.mouseState = SDL_GetMouseState(&input.mouse.mx, &input.mouse.my);
    } while (!input.keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE] && input.e.type != SDL_QUIT);


    glDeleteShader(shader.vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(shader.fragmentShader);
    glDeleteProgram(shader.program);
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    context = nullptr;
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = nullptr;
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: That's *almost* a [mcve].  Remove the unused SDL_Image stuff, merge the `glsl.h` stuff into `main.cpp`, and unify the code formatting.

Comment: Lol requesting 23 bit depth buffer... That's a first.

Comment: Xbox One uses 23 bit depth buffer lol

Answer (score 0):

The depth test is messing it up. This was discovered by the time honored method of *commenting out code until it works*. Of course, that doesn't always work when you're debugging the blank screen bug.

Why is it messing up? Because with `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` it seems you pasted wrongly and aren't clearing the depth buffer, thus subsequent triangles fail the default depth test (it is weird for you to enable the depth test without setting the depth function).